# How can I connect to SQL Server with php

Tags: php, sql-server

I want to connect to SQL Server on another server, please help me to know how can 
I can connect to database by pdo, odbc, pdo_dblib and the sucess or failed code.

Thanks

Comment: You need your IP added to the remote server for starters then it's just a matter of using the right host

Answer (score 0):

You could try using something like this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

On modern versions of php you can use mysqli or pdo.

PDO:

```
try {
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=DATABASENAME, $user, $password);
  // your SQL-query
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

mysqli_connect:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", $user, $password, "DATABASENAME");

if (!$con) {
    echo "Unable to connect";
}
mysqli_close($link);
```

make sure your remote Server allow your mysql-connect.

Further information at:
- http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.construct.php (PDO connect)
- http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysqli-connect.php (mysqli connect)